# What is most suitable way to create integer indexed list or dict of json array elements?

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I'm trying to find the best approach to append and store sorted json array elements in list or dict. 
I don't know which is better, easier and more readable for my case.

I have compiled a minimal reproducible example with comments of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import json

json_data = json.loads('{'
   '"data":['
      '{'
         '"#CLIENT":"AAA",'
         '"#HOST":"host1.aaa.local",'
         '"#GROUP1":"AAA-Group-1"'
      '},'
      '{'
         '"#CLIENT":"AAA",'
         '"#HOST":"host2.aaa.local",'
         '"#GROUP1":"AAA-Group-1",'
         '"#GROUP2":"AAA-Group-2"'
      '},'
      '{'
         '"#CLIENT":"BBB",'
         '"#HOST":"host1.bbb.local",'
         '"#GROUP1":"BBB-Group-1"'
      '},'
      '{'
         '"#CLIENT":"BBB",'
         '"#HOST":"host2.bbb.local",'
         '"#GROUP1":"BBB-Group-1",'
         '"#GROUP2":"BBB-Group-2",'
         '"#GROUP3":"BBB-Group-3"'
      '},'
      '{'
         '"#CLIENT":"CCC",'
         '"#HOST":"host1.ccc.local",'
         '"#GROUP1":"CCC-Group-1",'
         '"#GROUP2":"CCC-Group-2"'
      '}'
   ']'
'}')

# List/dict to store concatenated and sorted
# json elements by number of #GROUP<i> values
grouped_list = []

print('Processing JSON elements:')
print('')
for element in json_data['data']:
    print('Processing JSON element: ',element)
    i = 1
    print('Processing groups:')
    while i < 5:
        group = '#GROUP'+str(i)
        if group in element:
            print(group+' found in json element')
            #Here: append to integer-indexed list, dict or whatever
        else:
            break
    print('')

#for list in grouped_list:
    # Do something with concatenated json elements
    # 1st list should contain 'data' json array elements with only #GROUP1
    # 2nd list should contain 'data' json array elements with #GROUP1 and #GROUP2 present
```

Would be great to have a list/dict, which I can also access like grouped_list[2] or something, to get above json elements which have #GROUP1 and #GROUP2 present, grouped_list[1] to get json elements which have only #GROUP1, etc.

Comment: It looks like you already have the code to work it, you just need to push the elements into `grouped_list`

Comment: Your examples of access make little sense. Please [edit] your question and describe what the data-structure (list or dict) would look like for the example JSON data.

Comment: martineau, your comment "Your examples of access make little sense" makes little sense without a broader description of why you think so.
The example provided in OP's question exactly demonstrates JSON dict/list data-structure that OP wants to achieve - that is integer indexed JSON elements, grouped by number of #GROUP elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it using a dict.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import json

json_data = json.loads(...)

# Dict to store concatenated and sorted
# json elements by number of #GROUP<i> values
grouped_dict = dict()

print('Processing JSON elements:')
print('')

for element in json_data['data']:
    i = len([ v for v in element if v.startswith('#GROUP')])
    if i not in grouped_dict:
        grouped_dict[i] = []
    grouped_dict[i].append(element)

# Show that it worked
for n in grouped_dict:
    print(str(n)+' Groups in element: ',grouped_dict.get(n))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! This helped me to create final solution.
This had an issue with incorrect indexing in case if there is JSON element with 2 groups, 4 groups, but not 3 groups, then this fails. I adopted answer to count key occurrences with "key.startswith()".